# Warnings in Android Developer Tools - Eclipse

Tags: java, adt

I have alot of warnings in ADT (Eclipse) related to the import clauses.
My question is :

- If the package is imported, but not used - is it included into the result compile ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, compiler removes them after compilation. But two issues that might come up:

1. code clutter
2. If you import some classes from jar and later removed jar but not imports, then you may get compile time error